# The app does not start because of MassTransit. He has to register his dependencies himself

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, masstransit

My Consumer has this constructor:

```csharp
public QueueProcessingService(ILogger<QueueProcessingService> logger, IQueueRepository repository, ISendEndpoint endpoint)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _repository = repository;
    _endpoint = endpoint;
}
```

> System.InvalidOperationException : Unable to resolve service for type 'MassTransit.ISendEndpoint' while attempting to activate 'OrderConsumerService.QueueProcessingService'.

I tried services.AddScoped<ISendEndpoint, SendEndpoint>() and it didn't help.

Comment: post constructor of SendEndpoint, problem is application can't resolve SendEndpoint

Comment: How are you registering MassTransit as a dependency?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [article](https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration), you could find if you want to use `ISendEndpointProvider (scoped)`, you should firstly register the MassTransit inside the program.cs with below codes:

```
using MassTransit;

services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    // A Transport
    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
    });
});
```

Adding MassTransit, as shown above, will configure the service collection with required components, including:

- IBus (singleton)
- IBusControl (singleton)
- IReceiveEndpointConnector (singleton)
- ISendEndpointProvider (scoped)
- IPublishEndpoint (scoped)
- IRequestClient (scoped)